# Adding text on scatter plots using xyplot for log-scale axis

Tags: r, lattice, scatter-plot

I came across this problem when I try to add text using panel.text (or ltext) in lattice on a log-scale scatter plot.  I know for normal plot, you would use:

```
attach(mtcars) # using the mtcars as an example:

mytext<- paste("text here")


xyplot(mpg~wt, scales=list(cex=.8, col="red"),
       xlab="Weight", ylab="Miles per Gallon", 
       main="MGP vs Weight by Horse Power",
       panel=function(x, y, ...) {
         panel.xyplot(x, y, ...);
         ltext(4.5, 15, labels=mytext, cex=2)}
)
```

[image]

If I do the same for a log scale plot the text will not be shown.

```
xyplot(mpg~wt, scales=list(cex=.8, col="red",
                               x = list(log = T), y = list(log = T)),
       xlab="Weight", ylab="Miles per Gallon", 
       main="MGP vs Weight by Horse Power",
       panel=function(x, y, ...) {
         panel.xyplot(x, y, ...);
         ltext(4.5, 15, labels=mytext, cex=2)}
)
```

[image]

Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide a reproducable example? It will be much easier for people to help you with your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't make my question clear last time.  Now this example should do it!  Thanks SimonG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform your x and y coordinates to the log scale for your text.

```
library(lattice)
xyplot(mpg~wt, mtcars, 
    scales=list(cex=.8, col="red", x = list(log = T), y = list(log = T)),
    xlab="Weight", ylab="Miles per Gallon", 
    main="MGP vs Weight by Horse Power",
    panel=function(x, y, ...) {
        panel.xyplot(x, y, ...);
        ltext(log10(4.5), log10(15), labels=mytext, cex=2)
    }
)
```

[image]